# How to use elements stored in a list in a for each controller

Tags: jmeter

This is how the test plan looks :

```
Thread group
    For Each Controller
        GraphQL HTTP Request
            Bean Shell Pre Processor
```

1. From the previous thread I extracted an attributes' value from the json response. That attribute is an id and for each sample unique id is generated. I then stored these ids in a text file as I need to use those ids in the above thread.
2. In the pre-processor I have the logic to read the text file. Here goes the logic :

   ```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("${filePath}");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;
    List idList = new ArrayList();

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        idList.add(line);
    }

    String[] idArray = new String[idList.size()];

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= idList.size(); counter++) {

        idArray[counter - 1] = idList.get(counter - 1);
   ```
3. Now I need to use each Id stored in the array as a variable parameter in the graph QL request. So for such cases I learnt that we need to use for each controller. Now my question is how do I use each Id in the for each controller.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use ForEach Controller you need to set up special [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
id_1=foo
id_2=bar
id_3=baz
```

So I would recommend re-arranging your Thread Group to something like:

- Thread Group

  - Beanshell Sampler
  - ForEach Controller

    - GraphQL HTTP Request

and amend your code to:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("${filePath}");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line;
List idList = new ArrayList();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    idList.add(line);
}

String[] idArray = new String[idList.size()];

for (int counter = 1; counter <= idList.size(); counter++) {

    idArray[counter - 1] = idList.get(counter - 1);
    vars.put("id_" + counter, idList.get(counter - 1))
}
```

The [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) configuration would be something like:

[image]

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating to the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

If you don't want the JSR223 Sampler to appear in the test results you can add `SampleResult.setIgnore()` line somewhere in your script.

More information on these `vars`, `SampleResult` and other JMeter API shorthands - [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)