# How to parameterize data inside for each Controller

Tags: jmeter

In this case there is a thread group (Thread Group 1) under which I am calling a GraphQL request. Now say this thread group is executed for 5 threads. For each of these requests say a particular field 'id' is extracted from the response and is written in a .txt file.
Logic for this write operation is written inside a beanshell post processor.
Now there is another thread group (Thread Group 2). In this I have a bean shell sampler inside which I have written the logic to read this .txt file.
There is a for each controller in this thread group. Under this controller there is a graphQL request. This GraphQL request must be called for each of the 'id' (which is stored in a .txt file in Thread 1).
Now the challenge over here is that the GraphQL request under Thread 2 has a field by the name say 'email'. This request was earlier executed for only 1 'email' but now I need to execute this for 5 different 'email'. Which means that I need to parameterize this field. Now if I keep the loop count as 1 in Thread Group 2 and store all the 5 emails in a CSV file and execute then only the 1st email is picked from the CSV file. In another case if I change loop count to 5 then Thread Group 2 is executed 25 times because we have a for each controller as well. How do I address this issue. My requirement is that if say Thread Group 2 is executed for 100 threads and we have 5 emails in the CSV file then the 1st 5 threads should use emails 1 to 5 then for thread 6 to 10 should again use emails 1 to 5 and the cycle should continue.[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQbez.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put your CSV Data Set Config which reads emails under the ForEach Controller, this way it will read the next email on each iteration of the ForEach Controller according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)

Also I recall that [you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70234656/2897748) [were](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69218540/2897748) [repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70234656/2897748) told to [use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), if you're not paying attention to the community recommendations and official JMeter documentation maybe it worth choosing another way of looking for support?

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. The only reason I am refraining from using JSR223 is because I have already designed the test plan using bean shell components for this project.